# Total Combinations on Grid

Tags: combinations

I have a game board with **64** square tiles, and each tile can be one of **5** colors (red, green, blue, black, and white). Each time the board is created, every tile will have its color randomized. However, two tiles will always be white, and two tiles will always be black (so **4** tiles that will have an unchanging color).

My question is: how many different game board combinations are possible? For example, the first board (apart from the 4 pre-determined tiles) contains all green tiles, but the first tile is red. The next board contains all green tiles, but this time only the second tile is red. Is it as simple as **5^60**? Or does the pre-determined tiles change this?

Comment: If you mean that two *specific* tiles are white (e.g., the NE and NW corners) and two *specific* tiles are black (e.g., the SE and SW corners) then your answer is correct.  If you mean that there must be two white and two black tiles somewhere then it's harder.

Comment: Four specific tiles, yes. Thanks!